# Angular toggle background-image

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to change the background-image of an element when I click it.

Right now this is what I have:

```
<div class="item-center text-center" toggle-class="active cable"> 
  <div class="quiz-background"></div>
  <p class="size1 quiz-text">Cable</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.quiz-background {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-image: url(images/ofertas/Cable_darkBlue.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.cable .quiz-background {
  background-image: url(images/ofertas/Cable_lightBlue.png);
}
```

directive for toggle-class:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('libertyprApp')
.directive('toggleClass', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        elem.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

right now, the background image toggles because I'm toggling the class with the second background. But I want to be able to do it inline styling `style="background-image: url(...)"`and be able to change that inline background style.

Is there a way to do this with angular?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's what I've done so far, it works but I'm not if it's the best way:

```
<div class="item-center text-center circle-image-quiz" toggle-class="active cable"> 
  <div class="quiz-background" style="background-image: url(images/ofertas/Cable_darkBlue.png);"></div>
  <p class="size1 quiz-text">Cable</p>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.quiz-background {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.cable .quiz-background {
  background-image: url(images/ofertas/Cable_white.png)!important;
}
```

this way it toggles the class with the background image overwriting the inline styled one.

I've done it like this cause I'll have more than one of these elements which uses different background images when clicked and not clicked.

Comment: why not use `ng-class` or `ng-style`?

Comment: You can do it of course, but toggling classes is really what you should do. So you already have what you really need.

Comment: well I have a solution but I'm not sure if it's the best way, I've updated the question with the current solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup something in your controller like `$scope.toggledActive` and then you can use `ng-class` to change the background by switching classes, whatever. The `toggledActive` would then be changed to `true` or `false` based upon a button click.